# How should I handle an ASCII value when using Netty's LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder?

Tags: java, netty

I'm using the LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder class from Netty 4.0.33-Final.

The software I'm working on can communicate with a TV without the help of Netty, so I'm using Netty in a non conventional way here.  I'm just using Netty for the Decoders and the Channel Pipeline to decode messages from all sorts of different devices.  That's my goal at least.

The TV that I'm currently working on has a protocol command for Query Power, and the TV responds with a response to that command.  The response's first byte is a length value.

My software receives that response in bytes, and I'd like to decode it using Netty. When the TV sends my application a response, according to Netty's LoggingHandler the bytes I'm passing on to the LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder look like this...

```
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 38 30 31 72 6c 30 30 31 0d                      |801rl001.       |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
```

The first byte the TV is sending me is the length field.  In this example, the message is 8 bytes long (not including the length field).

The problem is that the LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder is interpreting the length field as a hex value of 0x38 and using the decimal value of 56 as the length instead of the intended 8.  Of course, this is logical, because the decimal value of the hex number 0x38 is 56.  I think the reason the logger is showing the hex value 0x38 is because the ASCII table shows that an ASCII character of 8 has the hex value of 0x38.

So the issue is that the message from the TV does not get processed, because the decoder is waiting for more bytes to come in to fulfill the 56 bytes that it thinks it needs for a complete message.

As a hack, I wrote this code to convert the first byte of the message to a value that the LengthBasedFrameDecoder could handle correctly.

```
/**
 * This is where I recieve the raw bytes from the TV
 */
public void receive(byte[] data, int length) {

    // rip the first byte off and make it an int
    int messageLength = Integer.parseInt(new String(data).substring(0, 1));

    // convert the int to a byte
    byte[] firstByte = { (byte) messageLength };

    // replace the original first byte with my newly created one
    data[0] = firstByte[0];

    // create the ByteBuf so that I can write it to my awaiting pipeline
    ByteBuf byteBuf = Unpooled.copiedBuffer(data, 0, length);
    channel.writeAndFlush(byteBuf);
}
```

I'm new to Netty, so I'm hoping that there is something I'm missing that handles this scenario built into Netty.  Can you guys help me find the right way to handle this?

Comment: 0x38 is also the digit '8' . As I cannot imagine all messages can do with at most 10 or maybe 15 bytes there is something fishy. Looks to me this is a textual header line. Try reading more, I would expect a 0x0a to follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the implementation of `LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder getUnadjustedFrameLength()`

```
public class CustomLengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder extends LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder {
  @Override
  protected long getUnadjustedFrameLength(ByteBuf buf, int offset, int length, ByteOrder order) {
    buf = buf.order(order);
    byte[] lengthBytes = new Byte[length];
    buf.getBytes(offset, lengthBytes);
    String s = new String(lengthBytes, CharsetUtil.US_ASCII);
    return Long.parseLong(s);
  }
}
```

Comment: Later on I found a similar solution.  I'll mark this one as accepted, since it's essentially the solution I found. I'll also edit this solution to include the code I found that does the same thing in fewer lines.

Comment: @twindham if you think you found another solution to your original problem, you should post it as a separate answer, not as an edit to an existing answer.

Comment: OK Shadowfax, I will post my answer, because I think it offers a some insight to how the ByteBuf object offers this functionality in its toString method.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is very similar to the answer provided by Josh Wilson.

I went ahead and decided to override the implementation of LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder as he suggested.  I just used fewer lines of code.

```
protected long getUnadjustedFrameLength(ByteBuf buf, int offset, int length, ByteOrder order) {
    try {
        return Long.parseLong(buf.toString(offset, length, charset));
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        throw new DecoderException(nfe);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I realized that I should post the work that is done in the constructors of the class that is extending the LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder, so here's the entire class.

```
public class StringLengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder extends LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder {
    private Charset charset;
    public StringLengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(int maxFrameLength, int lengthFieldOffset, int lengthFieldLength) {
        this(maxFrameLength, lengthFieldOffset, lengthFieldLength, 0, 0);
    }

    public StringLengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(int maxFrameLength, int lengthFieldOffset, int lengthFieldLength,
            int lengthAdjustment, int initialBytesToStrip) {
        this(maxFrameLength, lengthFieldOffset, lengthFieldLength, lengthAdjustment, initialBytesToStrip, true);
    }

    public StringLengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(int maxFrameLength, int lengthFieldOffset, int lengthFieldLength,
            int lengthAdjustment, int initialBytesToStrip, boolean failFast) {
        this(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN, maxFrameLength, lengthFieldOffset, lengthFieldLength, lengthAdjustment,
                initialBytesToStrip, failFast, Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
    }

    public StringLengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(ByteOrder byteOrder, int maxFrameLength, int lengthFieldOffset,
            int lengthFieldLength, int lengthAdjustment, int initialBytesToStrip, boolean failFast, Charset charset) {
        super(byteOrder, maxFrameLength, lengthFieldOffset, lengthFieldLength, lengthAdjustment, initialBytesToStrip,failFast);
        this.charset = charset;
    }

    protected long getUnadjustedFrameLength(ByteBuf buf, int offset, int length, ByteOrder order) {
        try {
            return Long.parseLong(buf.toString(offset, length, charset));
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            throw new DecoderException(nfe);
        }
    }
}
```